# Convert 4 Hex byte GPS data to degrees latitude and longitude c#

Tags: c#, gps, latitude-longitude, longitudinal

I have my Longitude in Hex FF676980(4 bytes), I want to convert it into degrees in c#, how can I do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update the question with the code you already tried.

Comment: Latitude and longitude are numbers with many decimal positions that can be either positive or negative. I wonder how that data was encoded into 4 bytes. How do you know the sign? What about the decimal point location? Your question imho lacks information so others can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Normally geotags are 24bytes but for photos where a precise location is not desired a 4 byte geotag is often used. So its only natural to assume that this is your use case, you should#ve just read the wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging#Photographs) and got over with it instead of asking.

Anyways heres your code:

```
public static (int D, int M, decimal S) Parse4ByteHexGeoTag(string hex)
{
   var deg = Convert.ToInt(hex.SubString(0,2));
   var time = Convert.ToDecimal(hex.SubString(3))/60m;
   var min = (int)time;
   var sec = (time%60)*60;
   return (deg, min, sec);
}
```

Note that you should have an enum indicating if its N or S, W or S, depending on wether `deg` is positive or not.